# Annotation @ApiModel doesn't work for reactor types Mono and Flux

Tags: swagger, spring-webflux

Swagger @ApiModel annotations don't generate api documentation for reactor types such as Mono or Flux. When my controller expects Mono type in save method

When I use Contact contact instead of Mono contact everything works fine.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
@ApiOperation(value = "Save new contact or update existing contact")
public Mono<Object> save(@ApiParam(value = "Contact to be saved") @RequestBody Mono<Contact> contact, @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
    return contactService.save(principal, contact);
}



@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@ApiModel(value = "Contact api description")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Id of contact")
    private String id;  
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Why this annotation doesn't work. Is it not supported yet or am I doing something wrong? Thank you.